# Using `window.location.hash.includes` throws “Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'” in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-2016

I am checking the URL to see if it contains or includes a `?` in it to control the hash pop state in the window. All other browsers aren’t having an issue, only IE.

The debugger gives me this error when I try to load in this way:

> Object doesn't support property or method '`includes`'

I get no error when I load the page in through the popstate.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        if(window.location.hash) {
            var hash;
            if(window.location.hash.includes("?")) {
                alert('I have a ?');
                hash = window.location.hash.substring(window.location.hash.indexOf('#') + 0,window.location.hash.indexOf('?'));
            }else {
                hash = window.location.hash;
            };
            if (hash=="#DRS" || hash=="#DRP" || hash=="#DFFI" || hash=="#DCI" || hash=="#DCP" || hash=="#DRP" || hash=="#DRMA" || hash=="#EICS" || hash=="#ORG"){
                $(hash+'Content').addClass('pageOn').removeClass('pageOff');
            }else {
                $('#homeContent').addClass('pageOn').removeClass('pageOff');
            };
        } else {
            $('#homeContent').addClass('pageOn').removeClass('pageOff');
        }
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            var hash;
            if(window.location.hash.includes("?")) {
                hash = window.location.hash.substring(window.location.hash.indexOf('#') + 0,window.location.hash.indexOf('?'));
            }else {
                hash = window.location.hash;
            };
            if (hash=="#DRS" || hash=="#DRP" || hash=="#DFFI" || hash=="#DCI" || hash=="#DCP" || hash=="#DRP" || hash=="#DRMA" || hash=="#EICS" || hash=="#ORG"){
                $(this).navigate({target: $(hash+'Content')});
                if(window.location.hash.includes("?")) {
                }else{
                    location.href = location.href+'?';
                }
            }else {
                $(this).navigate({target: $('#homeContent')});
            };
        });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `window.location.hash` in internet explorer 11?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

According to the [MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility), `includes` is not supported on Internet Explorer. The simplest alternative is to use `indexOf`, like this:

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: OK well now i cannot get this to work if(window.location.hash.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    //do nothing
   }else{
    location.href = location.href+'?';
   }

Comment: I need to add a ? to the end of the url if the url doesn't have one already

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer, but String.prototype.includes seems to be working for me on Windows 10 IE 11.

Comment: @troxwalt That's good to hear, but it still doesn't work on Windows 7 IE11!

Comment: If you are **React**ing, you can use [polyfill packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357349/6225838) and avoid manually adding polyfills...

Answer (score 57):

IE11 does implement String.prototype.includes so why not using the official  Polyfill?

```
  if (!String.prototype.includes) {
    String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
      if (typeof start !== 'number') {
        start = 0;
      }

      if (start + search.length > this.length) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
      }
    };
  }
```

Source: [polyfill source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: you could also use the polyfill from core-js found here: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#stage-4-proposals

Comment: @DavidBarreto indeed! And for [React, a more recent answer was added here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357349/6225838).

Answer (score 37):

Adding `import 'core-js/es7/array';` to my `polyfill.ts` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This was posted long ago but maybe this may help someone on the newer frameworks somehow however I think the selected answer should suffice for anything outside of special use cases.

Comment: import 'core-js/es/array'; as of 2020

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue with an Angular project. In my polyfills.ts I had to add both:

```
    import "core-js/es7/array";
    import "core-js/es7/object";
```

In addition to enabling all the other IE 11 defaults. (See comments in polyfills.ts if using angular)

After adding these imports the error went away and my Object data populated as intended.

Comment: This working for me. What does those two imports do anyway?. And what import fixed the includes error?. Or both of em are for the includes error?

Comment: Since IE11 is no longer receiving feature updates by Microsoft, the javascript implementation is dated and only has support for methods thru ES5. By importing these 2 files, you are adding the polyfill scripts for Array and Object thru ES7 which includes the 'includes' method.

Answer (score 6):

As in Internet Explorer, the javascript method "includes" doesn't support which is leading to the error as below

dijit.form.FilteringSelect TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

So I have changed the JavaScript string method from "includes" to "indexOf" as below

```
//str1 doesn't match str2 w.r.t index, so it will try to add object
var str1="acd", str2="b";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) == -1) 
{
  alert("add object");
}
else 
{
 alert("object not added");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used [`includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes) from `Lodash` which is really similar to the native.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ReactJs and used `import 'core-js/es6/string';` at the start of `index.js` to solve my problem.

I'm also using `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';` to support running React in IE11.

> react-app-polyfill
>
> This package includes polyfills for various
>   browsers. It includes minimum requirements and commonly used language
>   features used by Create React App projects.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md

Comment: I started manually polyfilling all functions that fail in IE11 console... Really appreciate your time saver answer. To add those 2 packages at once to your _package.json_: `npm i --save core-js react-app-polyfill`

Comment: Btw, `core-js/es6` seems to not exist anymore in v3, so just [`import 'core-js';` as suggested in Github](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js).

Answer (score 0):

This question and its answers led me to my own solution (with help from SO), though some say you shouldn't tamper with native prototypes:

```
  // IE does not support .includes() so I'm making my own:
  String.prototype.doesInclude=function(needle){
    return this.substring(needle) != -1;
  }
```

Then I just replaced all `.includes()` with `.doesInclude()` and my problem was solved.

Comment: `.includes ()` works on both strings and arrays. Your `substring()` solution works only with strings and fails with arrays. As answered by other people, using `indexOf()` instead of `substring()` is better because this works in both cases.